# How can I split string between group of word in python?

Tags: python, regex

How can I split the "Value1" and "Value2 from this string?

`my_str = '<a href="default.html" target="_top">Value1</a><a href="browser.html" target="_top">Value2</a>'`

I try to this but it's not work.

```
my_str = '<a href="default.html" target="_top">Value1</a><a href="browser.html" target="_top">Value2</a>'
for i in my_str:
    i = str(i).split('^<a.*>$|</a>')
    print(i)
```

Comment: The str.split() functoin doesn't take regex... use the regex module to use regex

Comment: Don't use regex on html, use a html parser

Answer (score 2):

You can use `bs4.BeautifulSoup`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(my_str)
out = [st.string for st in soup.find_all('a')]
```

Output:

```
['Value1', 'Value2']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do regex splitting on html, which again you shouldn’t (see bs4 answer above for way better answer).

```py
import re
my_str = '<a href="default.html" target="_top">Value1</a><a href="browser.html" target="_top">Value2</a>'
split_str = re.findall(r'(?<=>)\w*?(?=<\/a>)', my_str)
```

Comment: This yields `['', '']`

Comment: I was making an edit not having realised the OP regex did not work.

Answer (score 1):

One another way is to use cleaning techniques for extraction, you split on one character and remove out unwanted values.

Here's the code, I used

```py
my_str = '<a href="default.html" target="_top">Value1</a><a href="browser.html" target="_top">Value2</a>'

strList = my_str.split('/a>',maxsplit = 2)

for i in strList:
    try:
        print(i.split('>')[1].replace('<',''))
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

This will get you Value1 and Value2

Answer (score 1):

This works if you want the entire html element for each.

```
import re
re.sub("(a>)(<a)", "\\1[SEP]\\2", my_str).split("[SEP]")
```

if you just want the values, do this

```
re.findall("\>(.[^<]+)<\/a>", my_str)
```